# Python 3.4: Converting ushort to bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, uint16, ushort

I'm trying to convert a ushort to bytes. However, when I try this:

```
>>import struct
>>val =struct.pack('<H',10000)
b"\x10'"
```

Instead of:

```
b'\x10\x27'
```

Is this a bug? Or I am just doing something silly?

I'll be writing this data to a serial device.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `b"\x10'"` and `b'\x10\x27'` are the same thing. `b'\x27' == b"'"`. Try `print(b'\x10\x27')` and you'll get `b"\x10'"` as output.

Comment: Just a follow-up, won't it have any negative effects when I try to write that for serial communication? I had an issue before in one of my projects where the microcontroller just stops responding once we send a value like "50" into it. Thanks again, @Rawring

Comment: There are no negative effects because it is *the same thing*. `b'\x27'` and `b"'"` are **identical**. They are just two different things to write the same thing. Like you can write `0xA`, `0o12`, or `10` to refer to the same number.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @poke. I wasn't familiar with data structures that's why I thought I was missing out something with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an alternate representation for `\x27`:

```
>>> hex(ord("'"))
'0x27'
```

You won't have any problems converting back to the int representation:

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b"\x10'", 'little')
10000
```

Comment: Thanks, @Moses. I was just worried it would cause problems when I try to use write data for serial communication.